# Store credential in Android App

Tags: android, credentials

I am building an App that needs to connect to a Web Service.

In order to connect to the Web Service I need to authenticate with some credentials.

The users of the app won't need to login or provide any credentials, these will be added by me in the coding.

Is there any easy way to store in Android securely credentials? 
I need to mention that the Web Service is developed by another company so I can't do any changes on that side.

My main concern is that if someone will decompile the app this credential shouldn't be visible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can create a class and set your constants there and for protection against decompiling use pro guard while compiling your app

Comment: Did you mean htaccess and password?

Comment: see AccountManager class

Comment: yes, I have to store user and pass, and the access is made through http not https, thanks for the quick responses guys :)